# In R, how to indicate an argument by name when that name is the value of a character vector?

Tags: r, tidyverse, rlang, non-standard-evaluation

Let's say I need to do this:

```r
foo <- list(`a+b` = 5)
```

but I have `'a+b'` (a string) saved in a variable, let's say `name`:

```r
name <- 'a+b'
```

How to create that list with an element whose name is the value in the variable `name`?

Note: I am aware of other ways of assigning names to elements of lists. The list here is just an example. What I want to understand is how I deal with non-standard evaluation so that I can indicate to a function the named argument without having to type it directly inline.

I have read Hadley's *Advanced R* Chapter 13 on Non-standard evaluation but I am lost on how to do this still.

Any solution with base R or [Tidy Evaluation](https://tidyeval.tidyverse.org/) is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `setNames`

```
bar <- setNames(list(5), name)
identical(foo, bar)
#[1] TRUE
```

Or create the object first and then use `names`

```
bar2 <- list(5)
names(bar2) <- name
```

or with `names<-`

```
bar3 <- `names<-`(list(5), name)
```

---

Also, the `tidyverse` option would be to unquote (`!!`) and assign (`:=`)

```
library(tidyverse)
lst(!! name := 5)
#$`a+b`
#[1] 5
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. The first three methods, resulting in `bar`, `bar2` and `bar3` are a bit of workarounds... Is there no way in base R to still use `list()`? Regarding the `tidyverse` solution, is `lst` an exported function from `tidyverse`?

Comment: @rmagno  `lst` is from `tibble`, which is one package in tidyverse. `setNames` in `base R` is the easiest option in `base R`.

Comment: `purrr::lst`: `Error: 'lst' is not an exported object from 'namespace:purrr'`. My purrr package version is 0.3.0.

Comment: @rmagno. I edited the earlier comment.  It is from `tibble`

Comment: Yes, the last option is fine, I was just trying to understand how to do it with non-standard evaluation in base R...

Comment: There were 2 goals with this question: the pratical one of getting it done: your solution with tidyverse is just fine. Now, I also wanted to understand if it is possible to refer to a named argument by the value of a variable. But your answer is just fine.